# PHP fpm is installed how to configure it with apache?

Tags: php, apache, fpm

PHP fpm is freshly installed how can i configure it with apache?

`netstat -an | grep :9000` i have tried this command but it returns nothing i think I need to configure it with apache first

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong.  If you are using Apache, then you should be using mod_php, which is made to integrate php with apache.  Unless you really have some specific reason to use php_fpm with apache, which if you did, I don't think you would be trying to make this work for the first time, then you want to be paring php-fpm with nginx.

There are lots of how-to articles out there that will walk you through setting these up and integrating them.  Rather than a LAMP stack, people have taken to calling this a LEMP stack.

The best tutorial is going to be the one that your Hosting company provides, or if that doesn't exist, then at least one for your linux distribution.

For example, for Centos 7:  https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-nginx-with-php-and-mysql-lemp-stack-on-centos/